# I have got this warning: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

Tags: java, compiler-construction, warnings

My code is

```
 OutputFormat wOf = new OutputFormat( "XML", "ISO-8859-1", true );
```

help me to solve this warning....

thanks in advance

Comment: 5 years later `OutputFormat` is still at its place :)

Comment: It's gone now with JDK 9 I believe

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to not use that class.

Another solution is to ignore the warning.  Looking at the class, I suspect that this is the only viable solution ... if you stick with the Sun XML stack.

(FWIW - this looks like a mistake on Sun's part in integrating the Apache XML stack into Java SE.  The class should be in a different package that doesn't trigger this warning.  The original Apache version is clearly not intended to be "internal use only".  Another interpretation is that this is not a mistake, but something that Oracle intends to fix in a future release by providing a better API for controlling XML formatting.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat` instead of com.sun classes

Comment: org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat  was deplicated

Comment: "Deprecated. This class was deprecated in Xerces 2.9.0. It is recommended that new applications use the DOM Level 3 LSSerializer or JAXP's Transformation API for XML (TrAX) for serializing XML and HTML. See the Xerces documentation for more information." https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/other/org/apache/xml/serialize/OutputFormat.html