# how to overcome SuchMethodError: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat

Tags: java

I run into this error on one box but not another, when using code to "pretty print" XML:

`ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat.<init>(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;)V`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the box with the failure was running "JDK 11" so fix for me was to temporarily use "JDK 8" instead for now.  Appears replacement alternatives are discussed here

[I have got this warning: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5455132/32453)

See also [Serialize DOM to FileOutputStream using Xerces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257748/serialize-dom-to-fileoutputstream-using-xerces) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331063/32453 but I don't see an exact replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Solution applies to Android,
To solve this problem, I had to go to my `misc.xml` file and change the `project-jdk-name` to Java 8. In my case, I'm now using `project-jdk-name="corretto-1.8"`